# Зачем в symfony метод generateUrl

Tags: php, symfony

Изучаю symfony, читаю документацию. В разделе роуты https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html#generating-urls описан метод generateUrl.
Не могу понять какой функционал он выполняет и в каких ситуациях может понадобиться?

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function showAction($slug)
    {
        // ...

        // /blog/my-blog-post 
        // (Зачем??, если в аннотации можно указать @Route("/blog/my-blog-post", name="myblogpost"))
        $url = $this->generateUrl(
            'blog_show',
            array('slug' => 'my-blog-post')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну а если на проекте не используются аннотации? Ну и соответственно вы вероятно не поняли зачем используется аннотация `@Route`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Аннотация

```
@Route("/blog/my-blog-post", name="myblogpost")
```

**регистрирует** ваш метод `MainController::showAction` как обработчик при переходе на url `/blog/my-blog-post`. Всё.

Теперь вопрос - а как пользователь попадет на урл `/blog/my-blog-post`? Вы ему в телеграмм или по почте прямую ссылку скинете? Или все таки в списке постов `/blog` будет ссылка "Читать подробнее", которая будет вести на страницу `/blog/my-blog-post`?

Comment: В шаблоне с помощью встроенного метода path я укажу ссылку на требуемый урл <a href="{{ path('myblogpost') }} ...
Это ответ на ваш вопрос: "а как пользователь попадет на урл /blog/my-blog-post?"

И на данный момент вопрос остается открытым, если в аннотации к контроллеру описывать роут:
@Route("/blog/my-blog-post", name="myblogpost")
а затем обращатся к нему в шаблоне
<a href="{{ path('myblogpost') }} ...
И эта схема прекрасно работает, я проверял. 
То зачем именно внутри метода контроллера регистрировать какие-либо ссылки??? Для чего они нужны, если эти ссылки мы описали в аннотаци???

Comment: Ну а если вы отдаете джсон то как сгенерируете ссылку на урл?